# PDO errors not showing when php file accessed by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, error-handling, pdo

I have a php file that uses PDO to access sql. I am using Ajax to run the php script. So something like, (on button click ajax function).
When I run it through Ajax, PDO errors don't show. However, if I run the php file without Ajax, errors are reported fine. For example if I go directly to the php url.

My question is, how to stop the php script and display any errors, even when accessed by ajax.

Die() does not work.

I don't want to echo the error through ajax, I want the entire script to die, and echo the error.

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand that no PHP output can be shown in case of AJAX call?

Comment: no, can you explain this please?

Comment: Okay, imagine you managed to kill php script and echo the error. What a user supposed to see? Should all the picture on the screen remain in place or have it to be disappear at once?

Comment: You can of course display the whole HTTP response body of AJAX calls, which would contain the error. Displaying is up to you.

Comment: I really just want to do this for debugging purposes, so ideally a blank page with the error echoed. What die() would normally do, outside of an ajax call.

Comment: for debugging purposes you have to *log* errors, not display them

Comment: Thank you. Going to look into logging.

Answer (score 0):

The error page is getting returned, but it is being returned to the javascript, not to the browser window.

Most likely the the ajax call is not interpreting as an error because the page status is a 200, i.e, a php error page is valid html, even if it isn;t what is supposed to be returned.

Two options.

1. Don't do it as an ajax call until you've got it sorted.  If it is a `GET` then this is pretty simple, just plug the address in the browser window and see what it is outputting.
2. If you can't/don't want to turn off the ajax call, then in your dev tools in the browser, you can see the resources that are being returned (in chrome it is network tab for example), which will show you the output.